# How to put a React Component Inside a nest of StyledComponents

Tags: reactjs

I want to put the { GiAustralia } icon from react-icons/fa inside the about me, although it is a styled component. Not sure how to go about this or if it is possible? Wherever I put it, I get:

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

```
    import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';  
    import { CarouselButton, CarouselButtonDot, CarouselButtons, CarouselContainer, CarouselItem, CarouselItemImg, CarouselItemText, CarouselItemTitle, CarouselMobileScrollNode } from './TimeLineStyles';
    import { Section, SectionDivider, SectionText, SectionTitle } from '../../styles/GlobalComponents';
    import { TimeLineData } from '../../constants/constants';
    import { GiAustralia } from 'react-icons/fa';
    
    const Timeline = () => {
    
    return (
        <Section id="about">
          <SectionTitle>About Me</SectionTitle>
          <SectionText> 
            I am from <GiAustralia />
          </SectionText>
     .......................
    .......................
    .......................
    .......................
    
export default Timeline;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a component like you said, it should work with JSX tag.

Edit: I searched through the documentation of react-icons and for Game Icons you have to import them like;

```
import { GiAustralia } from "react-icons/gi";
```

Comment: Yup it is sorry, that was a typo. I get the error with JSX tag

Comment: I've edited my answer, now it should work with that correction.

Comment: Ah man.. must be tired and not thinking hehe. Thanks a lot! Should I delete this question?

Comment: I don't think you can delete it after you accept an answer. You shouldn't ask this in the first place regarding the guidelines of stackoverflow, but it happens to everyone.  Also, no one will try to find another solution to this since you accepted an answer. It's okay since you are aware of the rules :)